# Insert the newest record using Merge

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-server-2017

I need to merge two tables, and if a record is newer in the original table (i.e. OriginalTable), insert this record into another table (i.e. MergedTable).
If the record is not in the MergedTable, it works as expected, but if there is any record with an older date, I get the message: "(0 rows affected)".

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks!!

This is the original table

```
OriginalTable:
TABLE           YEAR_MONTH  DATE
ExampleTable    202009      2020-10-19 17:25:31.337     <-- This records needs to be inserted
```

This is the destiny table:

```
MergedTable:
TABLE           YEAR_MONTH  DATE
ExampleTable    202009      2020-10-08 03:10:26.013
ExampleTable    202009      2020-10-07 03:10:26.013
ExampleTable    202009      2020-10-06 03:10:26.013
```

This is the code I am using:

```
MERGE [dbo].[MergedTable] MT
USING (SELECT TOP 1 YEAR_MONTH,DATE FROM OriginalTable WHERE TABLE='ExampleTable' ORDER BY DATE DESC) OT
    ON MT.YEAR_MONTH = OT.YEAR_MONTH
    AND MT.TABLE='ExampleTable'
    AND MT.DATE<OT.DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (TABLE,YEAR_MONTH,DATE)
        VALUES('ExampleTable ', T.YEAR_MONTH,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need to do is change your DATE comparison from `AND MT.DATE < OT.DATE` to `AND MT.DATE > OT.DATE` and maybe add `BY TARGET`.

Here's a test you can run in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @OriginalTable table (
    [TABLE] varchar(50), [YEAR_MONTH] varchar(6), [DATE] datetime
);

DECLARE @MergedTable table (
    [TABLE] varchar(50), [YEAR_MONTH] varchar(6), [DATE] datetime
);

INSERT INTO @OriginalTable VALUES (
    'ExampleTable', '202009', '2020-10-19 17:25:31.337'
);

INSERT INTO @MergedTable VALUES
    ( 'ExampleTable', '202009', '2020-10-08 03:10:26.013' ),
    ( 'ExampleTable', '202009', '2020-10-07 03:10:26.013' ),
    ( 'ExampleTable', '202009', '2020-10-06 03:10:26.013' );

/* Add the record from @OriginalTable if it is newer */
MERGE @MergedTable MT
USING (
    SELECT TOP 1 [YEAR_MONTH], [DATE] FROM @OriginalTable WHERE [TABLE] = 'ExampleTable' ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
) OT
    ON MT.[YEAR_MONTH] = OT.[YEAR_MONTH]
    AND MT.[TABLE] = 'ExampleTable'
    AND MT.[DATE] > OT.[DATE]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT ( [TABLE], [YEAR_MONTH], [DATE] )
        VALUES( 'ExampleTable', OT.[YEAR_MONTH], OT.[DATE] );

/* Show the updated @MergedTable */
SELECT * FROM @MergedTable ORDER BY [DATE] DESC;
```

Returns:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+
|    TABLE     | YEAR_MONTH |          DATE           |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+
| ExampleTable |     202009 | 2020-10-19 17:25:31.337 |
| ExampleTable |     202009 | 2020-10-08 03:10:26.013 |
| ExampleTable |     202009 | 2020-10-07 03:10:26.013 |
| ExampleTable |     202009 | 2020-10-06 03:10:26.013 |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. What is the function of  "BY TARGET"?

Comment: @CristianAvendaño `BY TARGET` (target table) is implied with `NOT MATCHED`. You don't need to add it, but I always like to be explicit about what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause you need to adapt your logic.
Your query looks for every row in MergedTable where MT.Date < OT.Date. This would match each row in your sample since the new row has an older timestamp. Hence the WHEN NOT MATCHED is not used.

I would suggest the following:

```
MERGE [dbo].[MergedTable] MT
USING (SELECT TOP 1 YEAR_MONTH,DATE FROM OriginalTable WHERE TABLE='ExampleTable' ORDER BY DATE DESC) OT
    ON MT.YEAR_MONTH = OT.YEAR_MONTH
    AND MT.TABLE='ExampleTable'
    AND MT.DATE>=OT.DATE  /* <-- switched the comparison */
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (TABLE,YEAR_MONTH,DATE)
        VALUES('ExampleTable', OT.YEAR_MONTH,OT.DATE);
```

In words: Get me any row in MT where DATE is greater or equal to the DATE of OT. If there is no such row, insert it into the table.